# Can I use a LTO-7 Ultrium 15000 external tape drive with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tape, lto

Can I use an external tape drive (LTO-7 Ultrium 15000) with an Ubuntu Linux PC? Do I need to use any app for it or only the driver?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write and read data to LTO-7 media with Ubuntu. Ubuntu has a tape  driver called `st` from the beginning.

All you have to do is making sure that you have installed SAS card to your PC, connect your drive to PC with SAS cable, and then you will see tape device under `/dev` directory, something like `/dev/st0`.

You do not need to install anything. Now it is ready to write/read data. You can use `tar` or `dd` command that has been already installed. You can also use modern archive command such as `dar`.